# GND of 9V batteries in a circuit

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ground, voltage-source

I have a very simple question.

I'm building a circuit that uses some integrated circuits, some of them need 5V and GND, and some like opamps need symmetrical power supply.
In summary, I will need 3 outputs for GND, + 5V and -5V to power the ICs. So I'm going to use a kind of linear source with 2 batteries to convert the 9V signal to + 5V and -5V.
I will use 2 batteries in series as follows:

[image]

My question is:

**Can I use the output I have named "GND" to power the ground pins of my ICs?**

Another question:

**On the ground "REF GND", do I need to put some external GND reference?**

Note that if I remove this "GND REF" from my simulated circuit in Proteus, I can not get + -5V at the outputs.
I am using the arduino too, if necessary, I can use the arduino GND reference, and put in "REF GND". But is this really necessary?

Last observation. I will not use the 5V pins of the Arduino, because my circuit will need a lot of power, so I have the 2 batteries to power it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f27Wn2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do you have any "ground symbols" in your parts drawer?

These three schematics are *exactly* the same circuit. All the ground symbol means is all the things attached to it are part of the same node in the circuit. It simplifies the drawing, but has no relevance to the circuit.

You can use any node you want to power your ICs, as long as whatever is connected to "Vcc" is 5V more (or whatever the datasheet specifies) than "GND". Typically the datasheet also specifies all the other pins must be at voltages between the limits set by the power pins.

You could, if you wanted, use "Vout -5V" in your schematic as "GND" for an IC, and "GND" in your schematic as "Vcc" for the IC. Why not? There's a 5V difference between them, and as long as the other inputs to the IC are within the limits in the datasheet, why not?

Answer (score 5):

You won't get "a lot of power" out of two 9V batteries because they don't have it.

Outside of that, the circuit will work.

The "REF GND" is particular to the simulator, and you don't need it in real life.

You connect GND to the ground of the rest of the circuit, and that's it.

---

Back to the 9V batteries.

They have a capacity of a few hundred mAh.  If you draw more than maybe 100mA, then they will be drained in a very short time.

They are not designed to deliver large currents, and cannot do it.

Further, you are using linear regulators.  They work by throwing away power as heat.  Using linear regulators, you are wasting a large part of the little energy that  a 9V battery can deliver.

Comment: "You connect GND to the ground of the rest of the circuit, and that's it.". So I can use the part of the circuit that I named as "GND", to power the GND pins of my ICs. right?

What I do not understand is how that part called GND will provide me with a zero potential (or ground). Being that, this "GND" of my circuit comes exactly from the middle of my 2 batteries in series. Where the ground of one of the batteries is connected and also the + 9V of the other battery.

Comment: "Ground" is just a reference point that you define as zero.  It doesn't mean literally "connect it to the ground."

Comment: I know it is difficult to answer precisely, but do you believe that in the "GND" point of my circuit will not have 0V?

Comment: @ValterF - If you call your GND 0V then its 0V, you could just as easily call it 5v, then your lower Vout would become 0v and the upper one 10v. A voltage is the potential difference between two points, there is no concept of a voltage existing at a single point, it has to be specified relative to a 2nd point.

Answer (score 1):

The GND is only a used for the simulation and indication that this is a "zero potential" point (aka Ground https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_(electricity) ).
When designing the board, this point would probably be called a “floating ground” as you are not able to discharge to the actual ground so some layers of the PCB are used as GND.

To lower the voltage, you can either use a "Buck" or a voltage divider (the second is a more efficient way)- Why not use a 5v battery? I am not entirely sure how flexible is designing an Arduino board is.